# Redirecting millions of URL from /forum to /forums

Tags: url-rewriting

I had a forum with `/forum` but it has changed to `/forums`
I want to know if there is a single line code which can redirect my old URL to new ones. 
It is not simple redirection from `/forum` to `/forums`
The URL after `/forum/abc.html` are now `/forums/abc.html`
There are some 500000 URL that need to be changed. Could anybody help?

For example:

`example.org/forum/topic/144934-pio-threatened-rti-applicant/` is now `example.org/forum**s**/topic/144934-pio-threatened-rti-applicant/`

If you see above the change is just 'S' for all the 500000 URLs

I have already tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ /forums/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I am left with permanant redirection ony

I am trying this way
Redirect 301 /forum/42534-how-know-my-pf-account-no.html /forums/42534-how-know-my-pf-account-no.html

Comment: And what does not work with what you have tried? A simple `RedirectPermanent /forum https://www.example.org/forums` should be enough.

Comment: As @PatrickMevzek pointed out, you don't need to redirect as the millions URL's, if all of them are in path: /forum, then you can just take that path. Wih the code your provide it seems that these should work:                           RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /forum /forums